# Excel Export exporting same row multiple times

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, iteration, export-to-excel

I've written an export procedure for my vb.net application, which exports data displayed in a `DataGridView`into an Excel spreadsheet.

However, instead of copying all 23 of the rows in the `DataGridView`, it copies the same one, but 23 times. What is wrong with the below `For Loop`that means it only copies one record?

```
For i = 0 To dgvExport.RowCount - 1
 For j = 0 To dgvExport.ColumnCount - 1
  For k As Integer = 1 To dgvExport.Columns.Count
      xlWorksheet.Cells(1, k) = dgvExport.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
      xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvExport(j, 1).Value.ToString
  Next
 Next
Next
```

I need the field names copied, hence the `HeaderText` line and the `k` variable.

A snippet of my DGV, to show there are different records;
[image]

The resultant Export;

[image]

**EDIT**

As suggested, I changed my code to the following

```
 For k As Integer = 1 To dgvExport.Columns.Count
  xlWorksheet.Cells(1, k) = dgvExport.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
 Next

 For i = 0 To dgvExport.RowCount - 1
  For j = 0 To dgvExport.ColumnCount - 1
   xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 3, j + 1) = dgvExport(j, i).Value.ToString
  Next
 Next
```

But now get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on line `xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 3, j + 1) = dgvExport(j, i).Value.ToString`

Comment: `For k` loop exporting headers should not be inside other two loops exporting cells, and `dgvExport(j, 1)` should be changed to `dgvExport(j, i)`.

Comment: @BrakNicku, When separating the loops and changing the 1 to an i, it says "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" on `dgvExport(j, i)`

Comment: Your loop is: For each Row / For Each Column / For Each Column - I am guessing there are 23 columns.  Do one loop for the header text, then the main Rows/Column loop for the data

Comment: @Plutonix See the above edit, the code has been changed but to no success

Comment: is `AllowUserToAddRows` true on the DGV?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, it is. Should it be turned off?

Comment: You should probably enclose the line that fails with `If Not dgvExport(j, i).Value Is Nothing Then` `End If` statements, `ToString` fails for nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem of duplicate rows is from this:

```
For i = 0 To dgvExport.RowCount - 1
    For j = 0 To dgvExport.ColumnCount - 1
       For k As Integer = 1 To dgvExport.Columns.Count
```

The cells are being iterated too many times.  Use one loop to export the HeaderText, then another for the data.

---

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

AKA NullReferenceException

If `AllowUserToAddRows` is true on the DGV, it means you are looping one too many rows.  The cells in that row are `Nothing`, so you get a `NullReferenceException`:

```
 For i = 0 To dgvExport.RowCount - 1
     If dgvExport.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then Continue
     For j = 0 To dgvExport.ColumnCount - 1
         xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 3, j + 1) = dgvExport(j, i).Value.ToString
     Next
 Next
```

Or change the row loop:

```
' one less to account for the new user row
For i = 0 To dgvExport.RowCount - 2
```